# Animate or scale from center

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any ideas on how to animate the width and height of a div from the top center?
Tried using effect('scale') but this is based on a show/hide so snaps back after completion.

Then tried a normal animate:

```
$('.box').animate({'width':200px,'height':200px,margin-left:-100px});
```

This works, but as there is a line of .box, I want the others to react and push to one side.

Comment: Its about how this element sits in the page. This isn't flash.

Comment: Use j Query on the others to make it look like it's reacted?

Comment: Can we see a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? With the HTML and other stuff?

Comment: Yep fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dmYY3/

Comment: I've tried adding 'margin-left:-100' on the prev child to compensate but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. (on jsfiddle)

Comment: Ah think i;ve worked it out. I've animated the parent holder div margin-right back, so it appears as if it animates from the center. See http://jsfiddle.net/dmYY3/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fine Tuned

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/T7DFp/)

```
$('.day').hover(function() {

  if($(this).index()==0){
      $(this).animate({'width':400,'height':400}, 500);
  }else{            
      $(this).animate({'width':400,'height':400}, 500);
      $(this).parent().stop().animate({'margin-left':'-100'} , 500);  
  }          
}, function() {
   $(this).animate({'width':200,'height':200}, 500);
   $(this).parent().stop().animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 500);

});
```

Comment: Thanks Guys thats great. Just out of curiosity do you always use jsfiddle, seems quite slow sometimes? Just found http://codepen.io/ which looks interesting

Comment: @TomD I think its preference..and yeah, jsfiddle lags at times but overall it seems to have more functionality.

Comment: @TomD Don't forget to accept an answer if you got what you were looking for!

Comment: Just updated my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lsatdown/hHdqQ/ The slider moves to today's box, on rollover the slider moves back slightly to compensate the scale (so it appears to scale from the center). Any idea of how to make it smoother so when you hover from DIV - DIV the slider doesn't jump back and forth?

Comment: @TomD You just have to add .stop() on the first animation for the parent('div') http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/hHdqQ/13/

Comment: @TomD Also, you now have the issue with the first div again... here is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/hHdqQ/14/ check to see if the div that is being hovered is at 0px position left.

Comment: @TomD Lastly, you should add stop() to all animations before the animation starts because if you run your mouse back and forth quick over a bunch of divs, it sets off all animations and causes a loop.  Heres the fix http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/hHdqQ/16/

Comment: Right, just updated the JSFiddle with another issue I need to solve. Now we have the boxes animating scale correctly, i need to be able to scroll the scene left and right. If you look at this JSFiddle ive added slider buttons which move the scene left to right. Somehow, as the scene is scrolling I need the box thats currently in the center of the screen at that time, to expand automatically. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/lsatdown/hHdqQ/17/

Comment: @TomD I see what you are trying to do...the only thing is that the 'center' cover may be different depending on the size of the users screen...also, the slide buttons arent working for me...??

Comment: aren't they? Should be working on rollover and slide the holder div across. Basically its a developed version of a coverflow interaction. Im going to add a slider at the bottom to move them, but also was hover areas on the left + right of the screen to also move the holder div across.

Comment: I tried going to each box in a for loop within the setInterval to check if its in the center of the screen, then expand. But its too processor heavy

Comment: @TomD I haven't worked on the center cover, but here's a simple hover slide function http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/hHdqQ/20/

Comment: Cool works well and is less processor heavy. Would be nice to have it smooth linear motion when the mouse is constantly over.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to achieve the center cover auto expanding on as the stage moves left to right? @VIDesignz

Comment: @TomD Well, first we should center on start... check this http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/hHdqQ/21/

Comment: @TomD You wanna at least accept my original answer since it answered your original question?

Comment: sorry only just checked this page. Yep thats great thankyou for your help. Im going to try and just check the box positions on scroll, rather than setInterval as it will be quicker and smoother.

Comment: Added a smmoth scroll for the hover and fixed the centering (previously if there was an odd number of divs visible, it would center the space between, not the div) http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/zLxMw/

Comment: Brilliant @VIDesignz thanks. Thats helped loads. Just need to work out the auto box scaling when in center, ill do some more research.

Comment: @TomD Whats it gonna take to get an upvote? An 'Accepted' answer? x)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
$('.day').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({'width':400,'height':400, 'margin':'-100px -90px'});        
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({'width':200,'height':200, 'margin': '0 10px'});      
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmYY3/3/ ?

Comment: Thanks that works, however I need to surrounding boxes to reacts to the size change. Think i've worked it out: http://jsfiddle.net/dmYY3/2/

Comment: @TomD  That works good except when your on the left div... and the animation is awkward when you go from one div to another.

Comment: Yeah I;ve just noticed that, needs refining!